# Not all data transferred with WCF call with Entity Framework Include

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I have a WCF Service that is returning data from entity framework.  The object it is returning is a ShippingLine that is the child of an OrderLine which is the child of an order.

In my WCF Service I have the following code:

```
            var shippingLine = _dbContext.ShippingLines
                            .Include(l => l.OrderLine)
                            .Include(l => l.OrderLine.Order)
                            .Include(l => l.OrderLine.Order.Customer)
                            .Include(l => l.OrderLine.Order.Customer.CustomerAddress)
                            .Include(l => l.OrderLine.Order.Customer.CustomerAddress.Country)
                            .Include(l => l.OrderLine.Order.Customer.CustomerAddress.State)
                            .Include(l => l.OrderLine.OrderLineOptions)
                            .Include(l => l.OrderLine.OrderLineOptions.First().Option)
                            .Include(l => l.OrderLine.OrderLineOptions.First().Option.ExternalPrintingSystemMapping)
                            .Include(l => l.OrderLine.OrderLineStatus)
                            .Include(l => l.TrackingNumbers)
                            .Include(l => l.ShippingMethod)
                            .Include(l => l.ShippingMethod.ShippingRates)
                            .Include(l => l.ShippingBox)
                            .Include(l => l.BulkMailingAsset)
                            .Include(l => l.BulkPostageType)
                            .FirstOrDefault<ShippingLine>(line => line.Id == id);
```

We are using some custom extension methods around EF and Self Tracking Entities to help us write unit tests.  We have implemented our own Include methods that are being called above:

```
            public static IQueryable<TSource> Include<TSource>(this IQueryable<TSource> source, Expression<Func<TSource, object>> exp) where TSource : class
        {
            var objectQuery = source as ObjectQuery<TSource>;

            if (objectQuery != null)
            {
                return objectQuery.Include(ObjectQueryExtensionMethods.GetIncludePath((MemberExpression)exp.Body));
            }

            var fakeObjectSet = source as FakeObjectSet<TSource>;
            if (fakeObjectSet != null)
            {
                fakeObjectSet.Include(exp);
            }

            return source;
        }

        public static IQueryable<TSource> Include<TSource>(this IQueryable<TSource> source, string path) where TSource : class
        {
            var objectQuery = source as ObjectQuery<TSource>;

            if (objectQuery != null)
            {
                return objectQuery.Include(path);
            }

            var fakeObjectSet = source as FakeObjectSet<TSource>;
            if (fakeObjectSet != null)
            {
                fakeObjectSet.Include(path);
            }

            return source;
        }
```

The top method is the one I'm using currently.  I've tried using the second one that takes a string page like "Orderline.Order.Customer" with no change in behavior.  The top Include method is using this method to get the include path:

```
        internal static string GetIncludePath(MemberExpression memberExpression)
    {
        string path = "";
        if (memberExpression.Expression is MethodCallExpression)
            path = GetIncludePath((MemberExpression)((memberExpression.Expression as MethodCallExpression).Arguments[0])) + ".";
        if (memberExpression.Expression is MemberExpression)
            path = GetIncludePath((MemberExpression)memberExpression.Expression) + ".";

        return path + memberExpression.Member.Name;
    }
```

I then return this shipping line to an MVC controller that then tries to access the Order on the OrderLine object.  For some reason though every property on the OrderLine object is null or set to its default value.  So I'm unable to access the Order object in the code following because Order is null:

```
line.OrderLine.Order.Customer.CustomerAddress;
```

I'm using the 4.0 framework and EF 4 Self Tracking Entities.

I know for sure it is including the OrderLine and Order information because in the debugger I can see the OrderLine and Order correctly before it is returned to the client.

When it arrives on the client, however, all of the OrderLine properties are null or defaults and the Order is not there.  All the other includes seem to be working fine.

The relationships are Order (one) to OrderLine (many), OrderLine (one) to ShippingLine (many).

I've tried so far...
1. Updating my service reference on the client.
2. Deleting and re-creating my service reference on the client.
3. Turning on verbose WCF tracing on the client. I did not see any problems in the trace.

Any idea of why an included object would be dropped like that?
[image]

Here is my client web.config:

```
  <system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IMyService" closeTimeout="00:10:00" openTimeout="00:10:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00" maxBufferSize="2147483646" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483646" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483646" messageEncoding="Mtom">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="256" maxStringContentLength="5242880" maxArrayLength="2147483646" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483646" />
      <security mode="None">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<client>
  <endpoint address="http://localhost/MyService/systemservice.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IMyService" contract="MyService.IMyService" name="BasicHttpBinding_IMyService" />
</client>
```

Here is my web service web.config:

```
    <system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
    <services>
        <service name="MyApi.MyService">
            <endpoint behaviorConfiguration="MyServiceBehavior" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="MyServiceBindingConfiguration"
                contract="MyApi.IMyService"/>
            <host>
                <timeouts openTimeout="00:05:00"/>
            </host>
        </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="MyServiceBindingConfiguration" closeTimeout="00:10:00" openTimeout="00:10:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00"
                maxBufferSize="2147483646" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483646" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483646" messageEncoding="Mtom">
                <readerQuotas maxDepth="256" maxStringContentLength="5242880" maxArrayLength="2147483646" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="5242880"/>
            </binding>
            <binding name="ServiceSoap" closeTimeout="00:10:00" openTimeout="00:10:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00" allowCookies="false"
                bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
                messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
                <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384"/>
                <security mode="Transport">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm=""/>
                    <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default"/>
                </security>
            </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <!-- productionProxyAddress https://api.authorize.net/soap/v1/Service.asmx -->
        <endpoint address="https://apitest.authorize.net/soap/v1/Service.asmx" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="ServiceSoap"
            contract="AuthorizeNet.ServiceSoap" name="ServiceSoap"/>
    </client>
    <behaviors>
        <endpointBehaviors>
            <behavior name="MyServiceBehavior">
            </behavior>
        </endpointBehaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior>
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True"/>
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: Did you try to change the value of the `<dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="1" />` attribute? If set to 1 only the root level will be serialized.

Comment: From what I can see it is not being set in the code or the web.config, and the default should be fine unless you know something else about that.  I just added the web.configs for client and service.

Comment: Default value for `maxItemInObjectGraph` is MaxValue, should be ok  ;-)  Could you try to switch to `<binaryMessageEncoding />` rather than text (which is default for basichttpbinding)

Comment: I'm assuming I would need to create a custom binding to do that.  Haven't done that before, what would that custom binding look like to mimic basichttpbinding except with binaryMessageEncoding?

Comment: Try this:  `<bindings>
      <customBinding>
        <binding name="BinaryHttpBinding">
          <binaryMessageEncoding />
          <httpTransport />
        </binding>
      </customBinding>
    </bindings>`  and then on your endpoint: `binding="customBinding"
          bindingConfiguration="BinaryHttpBinding"`

Comment: Tried that, and I still have the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think the EF include lambda syntax for including collections is

```
.Include(l => l.OrderLine.OrderLineOptions.Select(ol => ol.Option))
```

rather than

```
.Include(l => l.OrderLine.OrderLineOptions.First().Option)
```

Comment: I tried that, but it doesn't work with our custom Include methods that we use for unit testing purposes.  I've added the code for those to the question.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by referencing a project (instead of the service) that we have called ServiceInterface.  The only purpose of this project is to have a service reference to our web service.  Because we reference the service is several places this makes it easier when adding new methods.  You only have to update the service reference in one place.

The only thing I can think of is for some reason the proxy classes that were being created on my MVC site project were not being created correctly when I added the service reference.  No matter how many times I updated it or re-created the service reference it would not work.  Using a project that had a service reference I knew worked did the trick.